# Prevent SpringBoot from creating an EmbeddedServletContainer

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to convert an existing spring application into a spring boot application. this application is not a web application but somewhere deep in it's maven dependencies hierarchy it includes a spring-web jar and therefore spring-boot tries to autoconfigure a WebEnvironment and in turn complains about not finding an EmbeddedServletContainerFactory. But this is intended as I'm using spring-boot-starter instead of spring-boot-starter-web.

My questing is: how can I prevent spring-boot from autodiscovering web specific items in the classpath? I already tried something like

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.class })
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Debugging the startup process I see that it runs into a method called deduceWebEnvironment() which is called unconditionally. This method returns true as soon as the following classes are on the classpath:

```
javax.servlet.Servlet, org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext
```

But again, even this classes exist in the cp, I don't want to startup a web-application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `new SpringApplicationBuilder(YourApp.class).setWebEnvironment(false).run(args)` You can also disable the web mode via configuration in `application.properties`

```
spring.main.web-environment=false
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-web-environment)